# postgres create extension invalid support function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am trying to create a operator class for my index in postgres. But when creating extension i am getting a error " invalid function number 4, must be between 1 and 3".
I dont know where this error is occured my operator class is

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS bool_ops DEFAULT
    FOR TYPE bool USING lsm3 AS
    OPERATOR 1  <,
    OPERATOR 2  <=,
    OPERATOR 3  =,
    OPERATOR 4  >=,
    OPERATOR 5  >,
    FUNCTION 1  btboolcmp(bool,bool),
    FUNCTION 4  btequalimage(oid);
```

Comment: Your access method handler (not shown) defines how many support functions there can be.  It must have a mismatch with what you are trying to do in the code you do show.

Comment: I am providing amstrategies and amsupport both 5

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  Where would the '3' in the error message be coming from, if not from the amsupport you provided in the handler?